# Adding compiler options to a stackblitz project

Tags: angular, typescript, github, stackblitz

I want to add a file tsconfig.json consisting of the following code, to a stackblitz sample here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1tbbrn. please anyone did this anyone did this??

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I see in your stackblitz... What's the problem?

Comment: You are missing the `ts.config.app.json` file. Its reference is in the `angular.cli` file.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi how to add them?

Comment: @KurtHamilton i want to strict mode on compiler for this current project... how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at an Angular project you create on your own file system, you will find an entry in `angular.json` like this:

```
{
  "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json"
}
```

When you look in tsconfig.app.json, you will see something like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json", // <------ inheritance
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

So you can see that `tsconfig.app.json` inherits from `tsconfig.json` via the `extends` attribute.

You have added `tsconfig.json` to your project, but not `app.config.json`, so it is not being referenced by `angular.json`.

Adding a new file `tsconfig.app.json` that inherits `tsconfig.json` should work.